# How to transform array in string of new string with comma and parentheses

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have a array of values that I want to transform in a new value of strings to do a query in a external service that accept the query like this:

```
/v53.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,Name,Field FROM Table WHERE Field IN ('a0C7X0000056xmxUAA', 'a0C7X0000056x9EUAQ', 'a0C7X0000056x99UAA')
```

example:

I have this code that transform the array:

```
mapIdGRD__c.map((num) => {
        return String(num);
      });
```

In this:

```
[
  'a0C7X0000056xmxUAA',
  'a0C7X0000056x9EUAQ',
  'a0C7X0000056x99UAA',
  'a0C7X0000056x8YUAQ',
  'a0C7X0000056wmxUAA',
  'a0C7X0000056wmsUAA',
  'a0C7X0000056wmnUAA',
  'a0C7X0000056wmYUAQ',
  'a0C7X0000056wmTUAQ',
  'a0C7X0000056wmOUAQ'
]
```

And I want to transform in a new string separated with comma and parentheses like this:

```
(  'a0C7X0000056xmxUAA',
  'a0C7X0000056x9EUAQ',
  'a0C7X0000056x99UAA',
  'a0C7X0000056x8YUAQ',
  'a0C7X0000056wmxUAA',
  'a0C7X0000056wmsUAA',
  'a0C7X0000056wmnUAA',
  'a0C7X0000056wmYUAQ',
  'a0C7X0000056wmTUAQ',
  'a0C7X0000056wmOUAQ'
)
```

Is possible using some standard lib of javascript?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: What is the point of this question exactly?

Comment: Yes but why would you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: @AlonEitan to make a external request like a put in the question

Comment: do you really wanna remove the square brackets and replace them with parentheses? or you wanna concatenate the array elements to form a single string with a form or "(XXX, XXX, XXX)"? your question is not clear.

Comment: @Moe yes because the service just accept with parentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this

```js
const array = [
  'a0C7X0000056xmxUAA',
  'a0C7X0000056x9EUAQ',
  'a0C7X0000056x99UAA',
  'a0C7X0000056x8YUAQ',
  'a0C7X0000056wmxUAA',
  'a0C7X0000056wmsUAA',
  'a0C7X0000056wmnUAA',
  'a0C7X0000056wmYUAQ',
  'a0C7X0000056wmTUAQ',
  'a0C7X0000056wmOUAQ'
]

const result = `(${array.map(n => `'${n}'`).join(', ')})`

console.log(result)
```